# apache fop: Problem generating a pdf from a xml and xsl formatting file

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I´m new to apache fop and xsl formatting .. I´m trying to genarate a pdf from a xml and xsl formatting file .

I´m getting this error on the application
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///C:/Worklab/apache_fop2/Files/Brief_Bausteine.xsl; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 79; java.lang.NullPointerException

the line 21 in the  Brief_Bausteine.xsl is :

```
<xsl:param name="showSubjectBlock"    select="fn:true()" as="xs:boolean"/>
```

The fn is declare in this line :
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"

I´m new to all this .. and can´t see anything wrong .....

Thank you
Roque

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `fn:` prefix. It's never needed, and with XSLT 1.0, it won't work.

Having said that, I wouldn't expect either a `SAXParseException` or a `NullPointerException`, so there might be something else wrong.

Showing the full stack trace for the exception might give clues.

Comment: The `as="xs:boolean"` part is also incompatible (and unnecessary) with XSLT 1.0

Comment: how the line  <xsl:param name="showSubjectBlock"    select="fn:true()" as="xs:boolean"/> will be ? .. I´m sorry to ask but this is all new to me

Comment: Try only this: `<xsl:param name="showSubjectBlock" select="true()"/>`.